# Как правильно задать лицензию LGPL для релизной программы на Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, лицензирование

Просто хочу узнать правильно ли я думаю. Допустим я создал релизный exe файл, разместил нужные Qt библиотеки для запуска в папке. Программа под лицензией LGPL. Я кидаю в папку проги файл лицензии LICENSE.txt c описанием лицензии http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html .

1. Достаточно этого чтобы распространять прогу?
2. Я хочу добавить еще свои условия дополнительно, например:
   "Данное програмное обеспечение используется вами на свой страх и риск. Автор не несет ответственности за возможные нежелательные последствия в случае применения данного програмного обеспечения." Ну я еще хочу написать что то типа что доступ к вашей файловой системе не будет использован хакерами и т.д.
   Я конечно все переведу на English. Так вообще правильно?
3. И Inno Setup делаю установщик с файлом этой лицензии.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Достаточно этого чтобы распространять прогу?

Недостаточно. Коротко по пунктам:

1. Qt использует не `LGPL`, a [`LGPLv3`](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-3.0.txt) - это важно!
2. Согласно п.4 `LGPLv3`, кроме помещения текста **оригинальной** (без перевода) лицензии - нужно в  исполняемый файл добавить ссылку/пункт, в котором есть упоминание об использовании библиотеки и лицензии, а так же ссылку/пункт, по которому текст лицензии будет доступен из приложения. Обычно это делается в диалоге "О программе". А лучше самостоятельно изучить этот пункт лицензии и выполнить все его требования, там их немного.
3. Можно распространять программу по нескольким лицензиям одновременно, например, LGPLv3 и вашей собственной. Но следует учесть, что вы должны обеспечить отсутствие конфликтов лицензий. Иными словами, не должно быть ни одного взаимоисключающего **требования** между всеми лицензиями одновременно. Тем не менее, запрещать **допущения** из других лицензий (налагать свои непротиворечащие требования) - вы вправе.

> Я конечно все переведу на English

Свою лицензию вы вольны оставлять на любом языке. Но есть нюанс. Действующей лицензией считается только лицензия на одном языке (это орининал). Какой это будет язык - решать вам.

Comment: Спс, буду работать.